# Guide user to WiFi setting in iOS devices

Tags: ios, swift, wifi

I need to guide the user to the WiFi settings in their iOS device with a button to let them connect to WiFi manually. I searched for it and see that there was a method called prefs but many comment that it's not working now.

Can someone tell me how to link the user to WiFi settings or any other place in their iOS device with Swift?

Comment: You can't. There is no public API for iOS that lets you send the user to the Wifi settings screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.

This used to be possible, but it was a bug in iOS 9 (which was fixed in iOS 10). It was never officially supported by Apple.

If URL schemes do exist to do this, they're considered private API and if you use them, they may result in your app being rejected during review.

You can open the settings app, that's documented and supported, but you aren't allowed to link to a specific area (such as wifi) within in it.

To open settings:

```
let application = UIApplication.shared
if let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString), application.canOpenURL(url)    {
    application.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

There's a thread on Apple's developer forums where they confirm this:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65007

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I know now what i will do with my problem .

Comment: i use your code but it guides me to my application setting not to the full setting. Do u know url that leads to setting main page?

Comment: @MinaHanna you can’t link to any specific page, including the main page. This code simply opens the Settings app. If the Settings app is already running (but is suspended), then it will open in whatever state it was left in before being suspended. It will land on the main page only if the settings app launches from scratch. Unfortunately, this is the only thing that Apple currently allows.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .